# .NET Forms Published Application Crashes and Requires Reinstallation

Tags: .net, forms, publish

I export my applications using publish forms. After successful installation, everything works well until a user is doing something in the application, the app accesses the database, I do not know if that is relevant but when the power cuts out, so blackout basiclly, the application won't start again, the application is that affected by that that it needs reinstallation. Any solutions?

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't even know where to start.

Additional Information: The name of the application is ODS.exe
Application Errors: https://imgur.com/a/Z873oGA

Comment: Is it a local database? if yes then database be corrupted after the crash and during startup your application fails to load and instantly crashes on this. Its recommended to have some logging during initialization.

Comment: It has only a remote database but I don't think the database it is affected because, they are multiple users working on the same program, if it was so, all of them would've went down.

Comment: Since your app crashes on startup you might be lucky to find crash logs inside windows event viewer. So Event viewer application > Windows logs > Application. Check there for logs or add some logs to the application yourself for the startup phase and catch on whats causing the crash and log that. It can be anything at this point.

Comment: I cannot replicate the enviroment here at this point, I need someone who had that issue in the past to look up the windows logs to see if anything poped-up when they run the app after a blackout.

Comment: May I add you somewhere so we can discuss more in private? Maybe I'll show you a bit of the concept of the app, to gain more information about it?

Comment: I added the link to see the windows logs.

Comment: Something is going wrong with loading in the configuration file. Would recommend to log the process of loading the configuration file. Also for next time use `Windows + Shift + R` to take screenshots instead of mobile photo's of your screen.

Comment: I didn't did the photos, the enginner did it in prod. How may I log the process if in the program the dll was never called/configured, it is something did automaticlly, maybe a library or something.